# class not loading in the url field type in volt syntax phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

my css class not loading in the volt syntax. my code is

```
{{ url_field("companyurl","class":'form-control') }}
```

this css class not loading in volt syntax. why? 
where as my php phalcon code does  load the styles.
pls help me.
This is my php code.It worked

```
<?php echo Phalcon\Tag::urlField(array("companyurl",'class'=>'form-control')); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In volt all of the options need to be passed as an array as the second parameter

```
{{ url_field("companyurl", ["class":'form-control']) }}
```